# Problems when centering elements

Tags: html, css, centering

So I've reverted to the basics to try and figure out what I'm doing wrong...

If this is my web page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    body
    {
        text-align: center;
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>
<header>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

It centres it fine, but if I add the style

```
width: 960px;
```

to the body style, the header element aligns left, and the content of the header element ('Hello') is centred only within the header element itself.

I cannot figure out why this is, or how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it completely wrong, leave the body as is, use a `div` with a fixed width say `960px` and use `margin: auto;` to center it, so the markup/styles goes like

```
<body>
   <div class="wrap"></div>
</body>

html, body { /* Irrelevant here */
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}

div.wrap { /* This will make your div align center */
   width: 960px;
   margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a "wrapper" div with all the content and put `width:960px; margin: auto;` on it.